# Como usar o for no Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Não consigo usar o `for` igual uso no `Java`.

Estou tentando descobrir se um dado é viciado. Um dono de cassino honesto o lançou `n` vezes, dado os `n` resultados dos lançamentos, determinar o número de ocorrências de cada face.

Comment: Por favor, mostre o código que você esta tentando rodar, para que os outros usuários entendam melhor o problema.

Answer (score 2):

A sintaxe do `for` em Ruby é:

```
for «variável» in «lista»
    «comandos»
end
```

Para fazer um laço que vai de 0 até 9 (10 repetições), algo equivalente ao `for(i=0; i<10; i++)`, você fará:

```
for i in 0..9
    puts "o valor de 'i' é #{x}"
end
```

E se você quiser, pode usar uma variável para indicar o limite do seu laço:

```
n=9
for i in 0..n
    puts "o valor de 'i' é #{x}"
end
```

Se você não quiser incluir o último valor, use `...` ao invés de `..`. Neste caso você obterá o mesmo resultado usando `0..9` ou `0...10`.

Comment: Só me ficou confuso se `0..n` para `n = 10` tem o mesmo comportamento de se usar a constante `0..9` ; pelo menos foi o que aparentou no seu texto

Comment: Opa, era para ser n=9, erro meu. Vou consertar.

Answer (score 1):

Os rubistas não são fãs de laços explícitos como `for` e `while`.

É muito comum ver laços usando iteradores, como faz o `Array#each`:

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
a.each {|x| print x, " -- " }
=> a -- b -- c --
```

Ou até usando o `Integer#times`:

```
5.times do |i|
  print i, " "
end
#=> 0 1 2 3 4
```

É claro que nem sempre o `each` ou o `times` resolvem seu problem, mas são raras as vezes em que precisei utilizar o `for` ou `while` no Ruby.